# JScript runtime error in Sharepoint Webpart

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to design a webpart that looks at a list of news items, and initially prints all the rows in order by date. If the user selects a type of news item, then only those news items will be displayed (again, in order by date). The problem is that my webpart keeps throwing up this error when I try to debug it:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error

And this mess pops up behind it:

```
    RTE.RteUtility.$1n = function($p0, $p1) {
if (RTE.RteUtility.isInternetExplorer() && $p0.tagName === 'TABLE') {
    var $v_0 = document.createElement('DIV');
    $v_0.innerHTML = '<table>' + $p1 + '</table>';
    while ($p0.childNodes.length > 0) {
        $p0.removeChild($p0.childNodes[0]);
    }
    RTE.RteUtility.$1E($v_0.firstChild, $p0);
}
else {
    $p0.innerHTML = '<div>RTE</div>' + $p1;
    $p0.removeChild($p0.firstChild);
}
}
```

The line: "$p0.innerHTML = 'RTE' + $p1" seems to be causing the problem. Well, otherwise, that's a really specific error message, thanks Microsoft. :/

The error seems to happen after CreateChildControls is called by NewsFeed.cs. My best theory right now is maybe something in NewsFeedUserControl.ascx.cs is causing an error, but as I'm a total neophyte at SharePoint I have no idea what that could possibly be. Is it because of this code in Page_Load?

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             list = web.Lists["NewsFeedLI"];`

```
         query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Headline' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query>" +
               "<OrderBy<FieldRef Name='Article_x0020_Date' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";

         SPListItemCollection result = list.GetItems(query);


        foreach (SPListItem item in result)
        {
            newsList.Text = newsList.Text + item["Headline"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            newsList.Text = newsList.Text + item["Summary"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

See, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try predefining the text that you return in your loop.  If the web part looks OK with basic text (e.g. "Hello World") but not with more advanced values then that it where your problem lies.

You will want to ensure that you apply the appropriate encoding to any output you are rendering to the screen as this may be causing you issues.